# cxDateNavigator1 set weekend days text color in red

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

In `TcxDateNavigator`, is it possible to mark the weekend (Saturday, Sunday) with a diffrent text color (red)?

TMS has this feature implemented but I can't seem to find that in this DevExpress component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the `cxDateNavigator`, you can use its `OnCustomDrawDayNumber` event handler, for instance, as follows:

```
uses
  DateUtils, cxDateUtils;

procedure TForm60.cxDateNavigator1CustomDrawDayNumber(Sender: TObject; ACanvas: TcxCanvas; AViewInfo: TcxSchedulerDateNavigatorDayNumberViewInfo; var ADone: Boolean);
begin
  if DayOfTheWeek(AViewInfo.Date) in [DaySaturday, DaySunday] then
  begin
    AViewInfo.Bold := True;
    ACanvas.Font.Color := clGreen;
    ACanvas.Brush.Color := clYellow;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

I would not recommend you to use red for weekends, because it usally indicates a holiday.

And if you want to know which date you are pointing at with you mouse. You can implement a `OnMouseMove`event:

```
procedure TForm60.cxDateNavigator1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  dt: TDateTime;
begin
  dt := TcxDateNavigator(Sender).HitTest.Time;
  if dt = NullDate then
    Caption := 'You are pointing outside the calendar area'
  else
    Caption := 'You are pointing at ' + FormatDateTime(FormatSettings.LongDateFormat, dt);

end;
```

Comment: any way to show a footer with 'Today dd/mm/yyyy' that would take me (on click) to today's date ?

Comment: Yu can add a cxlabel in which you display your text. If you want an other dateFormat try using FormatDateTime(FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat, dt).

As for your jump, when you assign a Data to you DateNavigator it will jump to the given dage e.g cxDateNavigator1.Date := Today; wil jump to todays date. 


If you want me to make an example for you, please create a new question